# How to create a related object via Rails command line / getting error for .build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a user which has a has_one to profile like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
...
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

I would think I'd be able to `build` a profile but I get the following error:

```
@user37=User.find(37)
[9] pry(main)> @user37.profile.build
  Profile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`user_id` = 37 LIMIT 1
NoMethodError: undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):9:in `__pry__'
[10] pry(main)>
```

How would I build this relationship via the Rails cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

has_one relationships are a bit different than has_many. Therefore, you will need to use `@user37.build_profile` instead.

Comment: cool - thx- have to wait a few minutes to accept. I think I've learned and forgotten that 3 or 4 times

Comment: Here's the doc for those generated methods (very handy) - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html